# Is there a codeigniter library user manager based on Ion_Auth?

Tags: codeigniter, account

I implemented codeigniter Ion_Auth library for user registration and etc.  I noticed it does not have a built-in user manager such as edit user accounts. Does a user manager such as edit user accounts exist? I can always code one, but I rather not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Ion Auth  too, it is pretty well coded I and I like writing code with it.

I also needed users editing, but I find it quite easy, because I needed only one simple form, because the library has **update_user()** and you need only to pass an array with your new data.

Comment: Alright, I will create a simple form, create a function to grab user information from the database, then transfer the data using JSON to the form text fields.  Finally use update_user() to update the data to the database.  Do you have a working example that I can work from?

Answer (score 1):

Download a CMS because it looks to me you have little or no experience with codeigniter or php for that matter. I dont mean that in a rude way by any means but if you cant perform simple CRUD operations, install a pre-built system as it will save you lots of headaches.

Comment: I rather not install a CMS.  The whole point of working on projects for myself is to learn codeigniter and php on my free time.  As far as headaches, there are none, just learning experiences.  I've created numerous CRUD operations in the past and present and it is fairly straight forward with codeigniter(saves loads of coding time).  Anyways, thanks for giving a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I've just started using CI and am also using Ion Auth for authentication. I'm handling user signup/authentication exclusively with ion auth and extending public profiles using Grocery CRUD. All public info can be viewed globally, but only edited by the user that owns it (as defined by linking the ion auth user table to the extended profile table). I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but it is what I'm doing so far.